# Compiling multiple lexers with flex gives redefinition errors

Tags: c, gcc, flex-lexer

I have two lexers - shell.l and javascript.l with prefixes (%option prefix) shell and javascript respectively(%option prefix="shell" in shell.l and %option prefix="javascript" in javascript.l).

I am calling the lexers from another file ( main_file.c) sequentially as:

```
somefunc(){
.....
shelllex();

......
javascriptlex();
}
```

In order to call these, I have included the header files of these two lexers in main_file.c as:

```
#include <.....>
#include "lex.shell.h"
#include "lex.javascript.h"
```

And, I create these headers when I compile the flex files as:

```
flex --header-file=lex.shell.h shell.l
flex --header-file=lex.javascript.h javascript.l
gcc -o lang lex.shell.c lex.javascript.c main_file.c -lfl
```

When I compile main_file.c, I get redefiniton error as below:

In file included from code_detector.c:16:0:

```
lex.javascript.h:227:29: error: redefinition of ‘yy_nxt’
 static yyconst flex_int16_t yy_nxt[][128] =
                             ^
In file included from code_detector.c:15:0:
lex.shell.h:227:29: note: previous definition of ‘yy_nxt’ was here
 static yyconst flex_int16_t yy_nxt[][128] =
```

I have gone through several other SO posts, but didn't find much help. 
I would greatly appreciate any help in resolving these!

Thanks!

Comment: What version of flex are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, there was a bug which causes the scanner transition table `yy_nxt` to be incorrectly written to the header file if `%option full` is present. This should be fixed in the latest version of flex (2.5.39).

If you don't want to upgrade your version of flex, a simple workaround would be to avoid using `%option full`. You may well find that the speed penalty is not measurable.